# Convert timestamp string to format "%d-%m-%Y"

Tags: c++, c++11, time, stdstring

I have a unix timestamp as std::string and I want to convert it to a beatiful, date string.
The already asked questions show only converstions with getting the current time (and use "auto", at all places so I am not sure what class is appropriate) but this
is an already existing std::string.

```
std::string beauty_date; //"%d-%m-%Y"
std::string stamp = "1567555200";
time_t stamp_as_time = (time_t) std::stoi(stamp);
```

I imagine this needs to be converted first to a unsigned long int (aka time_t).
My question is how to put the "stamp_as_time" into beauty_date.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: From the comments here is what I tried with put_time

```
std::string beauty_date; //"%d-%m-%Y"
std::string stamp = "1567555200";
time_t stamp_as_time = (time_t) std::stoi(stamp);
beauty_date = std::put_time(std::localtime(&stamp_as_time), "%d-%m-%Y");
```

This doesn't work as well.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Comment: I followed that and tried to     
std::tm tm = *std::localtime(stamp_as_time);
and 
beauty_date = std::put_time(&tm, "%d");
which unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: `time_t` is generally a 64-bit type nowadays so you should use `stoll` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work for you:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>

int main() {
    std::string ts_str{ "1567555200" };
    std::int64_t result = std::stoi(ts_str);
    std::time_t tmp = result;
    std::tm* t = std::gmtime(&tmp);
    std::cout << std::put_time(t, "%d-%m-%Y") << std::endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%3Ciomanip%3E%0A%23include%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include%3Cctime%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::string+ts_str%7B+%221567555200%22+%7D%3B%0A++++std::int64_t+result+%3D+std::stoi(ts_str.data())%3B%0A++++std::time_t+tmp+%3D+result%3B%0A++++std::tm*+t+%3D+std::gmtime(%26tmp)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::put_time(t,+%22%25d-%25m-%25Y%22)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++return+0+%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Or if you want to put it into a `beauty_date`:

```cpp
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(t, "%d-%m-%Y");
    beauty_date = ss.str();
```

Comment: Amazing! I hope such a function get's into std:: some day. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you obtain a C-string from `ts_str`? The `std::stoi` call creates another `std::string` from it. `std::stoi(ts_str)` is enough.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings oh, ok nice to know... thanks

Comment: @QtFan isn't it already in `std::`? Btw if you like the answer, pls upvote :)

Comment: @NutCracker I tried 10 reputation still... I am new at stackoverflow.
But when I get 15 I will come back to upvote!
Edit: somehow now it worked!

Comment: @QtFan You have enough now :)